# Store 2kb binary in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I got an app in azure, using azure blob storage. The app will recieve a lot of 2kb binary data, but when recieved it will be encoded in a format that will made it 4kb big (binary data encoded as hex-numbers).

The question is, when I store it in the azure blob storage, should I convert it to 2kb binary or save it as a 4 kb text blob?

Beeing a linux developer, if I did this on linux instead of azure, I wouldn't convert it back to a binary since most filesystems has a 4kb blocksize and the actual discspace used would be  the same for storing a 2kb or a 4 kb file. And converting from text to binary (and then back when fetching the file from the app) is just more work.

However, I've no idea how this scale with azure. And aside from the technical answer the economical is also important, how much more CPU will I need to pay for verses the extra storage for storing text files? (There should be a limit when a certain number of reads will make it cheaper to store the files as textfiles).

I'm talking about "a lot of" files. That's why this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you store 2K binary or 4K encoded text is completely up to you: It's an opinion question based on your app (which could end up with this question being closed).

From an objective standpoint: If you store 2K in a blob, you're billed for 2K (blobs aren't a 'file system' like, say, ext4). CPU-wise, you'd need to do some benchmarking to figure that out. But from a cost perspective, and storage being around 3 cents / GB / month, you're talking about 6 vs 12 cents / month for a million 2K vs 4K blobs.